# Linux server, setting up VM with different IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, ovh

I just purchased a dedi server (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) & additional IP's (called Failover IP's) from OVH. I want to setup a KVM virtual machine in order to for them to have their own independent IPs. Below is posted my /etc/network/interfaces file. This in its current state is making the new IP to ping from the server itself & my home computer. However when using the virtual machine wizard (KVM) it shows "eth0:0 not bridged". I'm assuming I have to bridge this connection in order for it to utilize that IP. Any easy way of doing this for a new dedicated server owner? Decently experienced with Ubuntu Server as its always been my choice for server setups.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 158.69.240.XXX (sensored my IP, but the beginning is accurate)
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 158.69.240.0 (same as my IP... except for last numbers)
    broadcast 158.69.240.255 (same as my IP... except for last numbers)
    gateway 158.69.240.254 (same as my IP... except for last numbers)

auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.99.229.XXX (this is one of the failover IP's)
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast 192.99.229.XXX (this is the same as address)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want the host to use the failover IP or the guest?

Comment: Is that `/etc/network/interfaces` of the host or the guest?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring eth0 on the host, configure br0 on the host with `bridge_ports eth0`.

The guest can configure its own IP when using a bridge, so you would not do that on the host.